# problem with the representation of trees with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I write that code:

```
     \documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone} 
     %%%<
     \usepackage{verbatim}
     %%%>
     \begin{comment}
     :Title: A simple Tree
     :Tags: Trees;Cookbook
     :Author: L
     :Slug: tree

     A simple tree with a style for all nodes.
     \end{comment}

     \usepackage{tikz}
     \begin{document}
     \begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=10em,
       every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
         draw, align=center,
         top color=white, bottom color=white!20}]]
       \node { (S , S)} child { node { (C , -)} child { node { (A , B)}                   child { node { (B , B)} child { node { (H , H)} child { node { (I , I)}  }          }child { node { (I , I)}  }child { node { (H , H)} child { node { (I , I)}  } } }child { node { (I , I)}  }child { node { (H , H)} child { node { (I , I)}  } } }child { node { (A , -)} child { node { (H , -)} child { node { (I , -)}  } }child { node { (I , -)}  }child { node { (H , -)} child { node { (I , -)}  } }          } } ;
     \end{tikzpicture}
     \end{document}
```

the problem is in the result:
[image: the output]

there are superimposed nodes, how can i fix that?

Comment: welcome to tex.se! reduce sibling distance at third level and increase at third second:  `every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
                             draw, align=center,
                             top color=white, 
                             bottom color=white!20},
        level 2/.style = {sibling distance=15em},
        level 3/.style = {sibling distance=5em},`. or better, use forest package. it take care itself, that nodes do not overlaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

do you liked? it is drawn with `fores` package:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree={draw, semithick, rounded corners,
         font = \sffamily,
    top color = teal!10,
 bottom color = teal!50,
         grow = south,
        s sep = 4mm,    % sibling distance between nodes
        l sep = 8mm,    % level distance
        }
[{(S , S)}
    [{(C , -)}
        [{(A , B)}
            [{(B , B)}
                [{(H , H)}
                    [{(I , I)}]
                ]
                [{(I , I)}]
                [{(H , H)}
                    [{(I , I)}]
                ]
            ]
            [{(I , I)}]
            [{(H , H)}
                [{(I , I)}]
            ]
        ]
        [{(A , -)}
            [{(H , -)}
                [{[I , -)}]
            ]
            [{(I , -)}]
            [{H , -)}
                [{[I , -)}]
            ]       
        ]
    ]
];
    \end{forest}
 \end{document}
```

solution with `tikz` is given in my comment below your question.

Comment: please, don't vote or accept before tomorrow :-)